# Flabbiness and sheaf generated by global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Maybe I have misinterpreted these two definitions, so maybe someone could please enlighten me. Isn't Flabiness for a sheaf equivalent to it being generated by its global sections? I have heard of the latter in algebraic geometry when discussing about sheaf of modules over a ringed topological space, but I suppose the idea of sheaf generated by global section can be extended to most categories. Well one should imply the other, and I would say (if I didnt misinterpret anything) that Flabiness implies the latter. If they are not equivalent the question can be extended as follows:

In which categories are they equivalent?
What are some simple examples of sheaves that are generated by global sections but are not flabby?

Comment: Are you working with sheaves of abelian groups on a topological space $X$? A sheaf is flabby if the restriction maps are surjective, and a sheaf $F$ is globally-generated if $\oplus_{s \in F(X)}  \underline{\mathbb{Z}} \to F$ is an epimorphism? Then clearly any flabby sheaf is globally-generated, but the converse obviously fails in all interesting examples.